# how to send/receive data with bluetooth between UWP(tablet win10) and wcf(win7)?

Tags: wcf, bluetooth, windows-7, uwp, tablet

Is it possible to send/receive data with Bluetooth between UWP(tablet win10) and WCF(win7)? And if so, where can I read more about this, I have googled, and searched for some examples or information about it. 
All help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of data you want to send/receive? Files?

Comment: commands , strings and ints

Comment: You can find UWP bluetooth sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples).  For WCF, [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50087c70-defa-44bf-a9c3-77258b0c7dec/consuming-wcf-services-over-bluetooth?forum=wcf) maybe helpful for you.